# Trouble understanding the Berkeley Algorithm

Tags: computer-science, distributed-computing

I've been reading and trying to wrap my head around the [Berkeley Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_algorithm).

The Berkeley algorithm tells us that the leader will from time to time ask all the other processes their current time, calculate the mean value over all those times, sending back to each one of the processes a delta value, that is the difference between that process' time from the mean value.

For instance, consider a 3-process system with processes `A`, `B` and `C`, being `A` the leader.

Now, if I'm correct, one should expect that if `B` has a drift value of 0.001 (that is, it will for each 1000 real seconds only tick 999 times) and I want to make sure that no process ever goes out of tune by more than 0.1 seconds,  I'd say that one would have to force the clock's synchronization every 100 seconds. That means the expression I'm using is

[image]

being:

- delta_t the maximum time I'm allowed to wait before synchronizing the
  clocks again;
- delta the maximum clock error; rho the drift rate;
- rho = drift

My problem is that in my professor's notes, one can find the following expression instead:

[image]

which can also be found in other literature sources. Can anyone explain me why do we have that 2 in the 2nd expression? I'm not sure the variables really are what I'm assuming them to be.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(small disclaimer: I haven't done much distributed computing. It is possible that I have misunderstood the problem. Why not ask the professor?)*

I believe that the division by two is to account for positive and negative drift on several processes.

If your worst-case drift is `0.001`, consider `B` has drift `+0.001` and `C` has `-0.001`. If you pick *delta-t* according to your initial formula, the time difference between `B` and `C` might become twice as large as the *delta* you want before you synchronize.